# button not opening doInBackground(void... params)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to send an image to the server. What is happening is that the button is not working... Nothing happens when I click on it.

void onCreate

```
 imageToUpload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageToUpload);
 bUploadImage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUploadImage);
 uploadImageName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUploadName);

 imageToUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
```

void onClick

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageToUpload:
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            break;
        case R.id.bUploadImage: //HERE, THE BUTTON THAT I WANT TO WORK
            Bitmap image =  ((BitmapDrawable) imageToUpload.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            new UploadImage(image, uploadImageName.getText().toString()).execute();
    }
}

   private class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        Bitmap image;
        String name;

        public UploadImage(Bitmap image, String name){
            this.image = image;
            this.name = name;
        }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UPLOADING...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ...
```

What is the problem that `doInBackground` is not being called when I press the button `R.id.bUploadImage`?

Comment: `bUploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialize your `bUploadImage` button with listener

```
bUploadImage.setOnClickListener(this);
```

because currently only `case R.id.imageToUpload` is getting executed

Comment: @RickJoe i am glad that i could help and happy coding